# First hadoop project error: "Input path does not exist"

Tags: hadoop

To setup a simple hadoop project I'm following this tutorial : http://ebiquity.umbc.edu/Tutorials/Hadoop/23%20-%20create%20the%20project.html

My hadoop single node seems to be running correctly.

When I specify the `In` folder using this code :

```
FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path("In"));
```

I receive this error:

```
13/03/03 22:05:27 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:DEVUSER cause:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9100/user/DEVUSER/In
```

Currently the `In` folder is created at `C:\homedir\hadoop-1.0.4\In`

Where do I need to create the "In" folder so that it appears in `hdfs://localhost:9100/user/DEVUSER/In`? Do I need to update an xml file to point to a folder on my local file system?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to upload your input files to the HDFS file system first:

```
bin/hadoop fs -mkdir In
```

will create a directory named `/user/DEVUSER/In` in HDFS.

```
bin/hadoop fs -put *.txt In
```

will copy all `*.txt` files from the current directory to the cluster (HDFS).

You seem to have skipped the chapter [Upload data](http://ebiquity.umbc.edu/Tutorials/Hadoop/20%20-%20upload%20data.html) from the tutorial. Follow it and your problem should be solved.

Comment: dear where these files are physically stored in filesystem ? so i can remove output directory?

Comment: You mean the files stored in HDFS? HDFS is a distributed file system. So the files are stored on multiple hosts. You cannot access or modify the physical files directly. You have to use HDFS commands to delete them. Please post your inquiry as a new question and provide enough detail.

Comment: i got the answer from your information that we have to modify HDFS dir via commands , thanks for the info

Comment: i have another problem, can you please tell me why i'm getting the classNotFound exception on running jar, i'll give you link of the question

Comment: I have images(jpeg) files as input to my map program. I copied all the files to ~/hadoop/hds/data/ folderusing bin/hadoop fs -put .... command. I specified /~hadoop/hdfs/data/ as my input path to my jar file. Still getting the above error. What am I missing, any help is highly appreciated?

Answer (score 2):

If you dont want to upload the file to hdfs rather access it from your local system, then try setting you input path like this.

```
FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path("file://path of the In Folder on your File system "));
```

Answer (score 1):

As harpun said, but for some situation even you tried to create that directory under HDFS, it wont and gives you that message : mkdir: `In': No such file or directory
As a solution to that you need to :

> bin/hadoop fs -mkdir /tmp/In

and then copy the texts files to HDFS Cluster

> bin/hadoop fs -put *.txt /tmp/In