# Unable to view any folders on DFS locations connecting to hadoop from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, apache, hadoop, cygwin, hadoop-plugins

I have setup Hadoop1.2.1 in windows with CYGWIN installed.
I have started sshd service.
Also started namenode, datanode, mapreduce (job tracker, task tracker). I am able to see the namenode, datanode and mapreduce running status through the following URLs.

When i try connecting the hadoop through eclipse, i am able to.Though i was able to connect hadoop from eclipse, i was not seeing any folders on opening DFS locations. Its displaying as (0) (refer Pic #1 ,
[image] which i guess no directories/files available. The same i checked with namenode storage (refer Pic #2)

Even when i try creating a directory through CYGWIN terminal (refer Pic #4), i was not able to see it in DFS locations in eclipse environment.
[image]

That being said, i tried with WordCount example, by setting the input path and output path as follows, 
// specify input and output dirs

```
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf, new Path("Input")); 
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path("Output"));
```

When i run that in HDFS location from eclipse, i was getting the following exception

**13/10/30 06:52:44 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:Administrator cause:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost:47110/user/Administrator/Input
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost:47110/user/Administrator/Input**

Questions:
Why i am not able to see the directory that i created through CYGWIN terminal and any folders for that matter?
What does "hdfs://localhost:47110" point to?
Am i getting the above exception since it dont see the directory in datanode?
What is the input path should i set?

Please advice me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please someone answer this

Comment: -try running your cygwin with administrative privileges -helpful links: similar prob asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191832/first-hadoop-project-error-input-path-does-not-exist) and read [this](http://ebiquity.umbc.edu/Tutorials/Hadoop/20%20-%20upload%20data.html) -try uploading your files in the newly created directory (follow 2nd link; its a tutorial) also have you uploaded the data correctly? Update: Apparently running cygwin with admin. priv. won't do much good :D nvm

Comment: @embeddedEnthusiast : Thanks for responding. Any reasons why i was not able to view any folders inside dfs locations in eclipse? (as per the Pic #1)

Comment: to all viewers, i am just curious to know why this question is not answered. Really disappointed

Comment: did you configure your eclipse with your hadoop clusetr...

Answer (score 3):

1st you should have check the all the setting of your hadoop cluster from scratch beacuse this problem shows that you have not configure your eclipse properly with the hadoop cluster

see the following link which help you...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TavehEdfNDk

also check you dfs is connected to your cluster or not means are able to store file and in your dfs or not..