# Hadoop cannot find my input file

Tags: java, hadoop

I am  trying to play a tutorial ([see here](http://www.bigsql.org/se/tutorial.jsp)) on Hadoop / Hbase / etc and have some troubles playing it.

I installed hadoop and hbase, made links between my file on my machine, but hadoop doesn't find my file:

I tried to import a csv file playing the following command:

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv '-Dimporttsv.separator=,'  -Dimporttsv.columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY,stats:o_id,stats:o_w_id,stats:o_all_local,stats:o_entry_d oorder  /user/data/example/haddop_order/order.csv
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:dev_user cause:org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://my_machine:9000/user/data/example/haddop_order/order.csv
```

But when I check wether the file is here:

```
hadoop dfs -ls  /user/data/example/hadoop_order/

Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   1 dev_user supergroup    1486038 2014-01-20 11:26 /user/data/example/hadoop_order/order.csv
```

Any idea of what's wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [First hadoop project error: "Input path does not exist"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191832/first-hadoop-project-error-input-path-does-not-exist)

Comment: Check out the accepted answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/15191954/1173560

Answer (score 0):

Typo in your command

directory name - `hadoop_order`

typo - `haddop_order`